# Why shouldn't I iterate over pandas dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, iterator

I'm currently developing some code that iterates over the rows of a dataframe with `iterrows()`. I understand this shouldn't be done, but I just wanted some more specific information as to why. I was under the impression it was only because of (what I know to be rather significant) efficiency reasons, but I lately read something about possible type change problems when iterating.

My current applications cannot be done in any vectorized way that I have found (I have to find .grib files that match the date and time of each row on my dataframe, open them using pygrib, change the format of its values, and even run an if statement in the process). I assumed that my specific needs could only be solved by iterating over the rows of the dataframe. So, am I making a mistake? Am I modifying my original data in a way that could cause issues? Is there a way to vectorize or optimize an application like the one I described?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Given your described logic and if efficiency is not a concern, then it's probably fine to use `iterrows`. You might want to try [`itertuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html) that should be more efficient. Hard to discuss this further without a clear reproducible example.

Comment: To add on what @mozway said, `iterrows` is generally slower than `itertuples`, because it slices the dataframe horizontally, creating a `pd.Series` of `object` type, unless your data is single-dtype across the columns. This might be the type change that you read.

Comment: The main canonical for how to do such iteration, includes the exact standard reasons "why not" in the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @mozway and Quang Hoang, I switched to itertuples and, even though my program does not run for that long, it is noticeably faster, and I'm now more sure about what I'm doing. Have a good one!